# Chrome and Firefox max out CPU usage after recent update, rendering computer unusable

Tags: 20.04, cpu-load

I have system that is several years old and has been running well. A while ago I updated the OS 20.04.5 LTS and things still seemed pretty good.

More recently I approved a normal suggested update that popped up on screen. Since that update, running the Chrome web browser pegs all 4 cores at 95+%. RAM usage is high, but not crazy. Of course this makes the computer essentially useless. I tried Firefox, and it does basically the same thing.

Any idea whats going on? Should I just revert back to an earlier LTS version? (if so, how would I do that?)

Thanks.

Comment: You can not revert or roll back versions of the OS. That requires a re install.

Comment: try to renice them maybe. sudo renice -n 20 $(pidof firefox)